# Getting app freeze and cell becomes empty when prepareForReuse used

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have tried prepareforreuse but now my app getting stuck while scrolling and cell is empty. 
Is there any wrong I'm doing? All my subviews are added in XIB.

Guide me proper solutions.

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"pollCell";

    IXPollCustomCell *pollCell = (IXPollCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];


    if (pollCell == nil) {

        pollCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXPollCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        pollCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

**IXPollCustomCell.m**

```
   - (void)prepareForReuse
 {
[[self.contentView viewWithTag:2001] removeFromSuperview]; //Does not crash if the view is nil. It's okay to send messages to nil in ObjC

 }
```

**IXPollCustomCell.h**

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *multiChoiceView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *multiOption1View;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *choice1RateLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *color1Label;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *option1Button;
```

Comment: read the documentation on `prepareForReuse`, it's meant to make changes not related to content

Comment: yes, but once i removed the contentview from cell, how to re add that?

Comment: Did you try to just set the view you want to remove as `hidden = YES` and to `NO` when you want to redisplay it ?

Comment: the point is that you *dont* remove the `contentView` from the cell. it's up to `cellForRow:` to change the content, not `prepareForReuse:`

Comment: yes, I have tried  hidden = YES and NO but still the contents are there

Comment: @LouisTur So, how can i do that? Any other solutions?